# Repeat a Number N Times in an Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, repeat

Working with Excel VBA.

I'm trying to create an array with repetitive patterns like this:

```
a = Array(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
```

Is there a neat solution (without going through a loop) to do this? In almost any other statistical language this is done with a repeat function. For example the "rep" function in R or the "repmat" fuction in Matlab:

```
a = [repmat(1,1,5),repmat(2,1,6)]
```

The reason not to hard-code everything in the first place is because the actual array has varying length depending on some other variables.

Comment: Can you not use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Output:** A,B,B,1,1,1,2,2,2,2

```
Sub ArrayHack()
    Dim a()

    BuildArray a, "A", 1
    BuildArray a, "B", 2
    BuildArray a, 1, 3
    BuildArray a, 2, 4

    Debug.Print Join(a, ",")

End Sub

Function BuildArray(a As Variant, v As Variant, n As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer, count As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
        count = UBound(a)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ReDim a(0)
            count = -1
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim Preserve a(count + n)

    For i = 1 To n
        a(count + i) = v
    Next

End Function
```

---

**Output:** 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2

```
Sub ArrayHack2()
    Dim a
    Dim s As String
    s = Replace(String(5, ","), ",", 1 & ",") & Replace(String(5, ","), ",", 2 & ",")
    s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)

    a = Split(s, ",")

    Debug.Print Join(a, ",")

End Sub
```

Comment: Your first solution is pretty elegant. I like the way it can flexibly redim an array.

Comment: Much appreciated.  This will do the job and is indeed flexible.  Obviously there's no built-in function that tackles this.  I think you and @JohnColeman basically created this function for me.  A loop is unavoidable then.

Comment: Thanks for the check mark!  It was an interesting question. It would be interesting to combine  John Coleman's answer with my own.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a somewhat flexible function:

```
Function BuildArray(ParamArray params()) As Variant
    Dim A As Variant, v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, n As Long, m As Long, b As Long

    n = UBound(params)

    If n Mod 2 = 0 Then
        b = params(n)
        n = n - 1
    End If

    For i = 1 To n Step 2
        m = m + params(i)
    Next i

    ReDim A(b To b + m - 1)
    k = b

    For i = 0 To n - 1 Step 2
        v = params(i)
        For j = 1 To params(i + 1)
            A(k) = v
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    BuildArray = A
End Function
```

It takes any number of arguments. If there is an even number of arguments it breaks them into successive pairs of the form `v,i` where `v` is a value and `i` is the number of times to repeat the value, returning the resulting array with first index 0. If there is an odd number of passed parameters, the last parameter is interpreted as the base of the array. For example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim A As Variant

    A = BuildArray(1, 3, 2, 4) 'creates 0-based array [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
    'verify:
    Debug.Print "A = " & LBound(A) & " to " & UBound(A)
    Debug.Print "Items: " & Join(A, ",")

    A = BuildArray(1, 3, 2, 4, 1) 'creates 1-based array [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
    'verify:
    Debug.Print "A = " & LBound(A) & " to " & UBound(A)
    Debug.Print "Items: " & Join(A, ",")
End Sub
```

Output:

```
A = 0 to 6
Items: 1,1,1,2,2,2,2
A = 1 to 7
Items: 1,1,1,2,2,2,2
```

Comment: I wish I would have thought to use ParamArray.  I would prefer isBase1 over the non-paired value.  It sucks that you cannot have optional parameters with a ParamArray.

Comment: @ThomasInzina Yes, I found myself wishing that I could use both a paramarray and an optional parameter (though perhaps there is *some* way -- I am not 100% sure that I'm not missing something). I tend to do more Python programming than VBA programming anymore, and often find myself missing some of Python's power and flexibility whenever I return to VBA. In Python such a thing would be easy. My function could be modified so that the last optional argument could be `True` or `False` rather than (or in addition to) an int -- with `True` perhaps interpreted as "Base1".

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Const U = 11                                        'U = (4 + Max(i)) * Max(i) + Max(j)
Sub ManipulatingArray()
Dim InputArray As String, i As Long, j As Long, MyArray(1 To U) As Variant
For i = 0 To 1
    For j = 1 To 5 + i
        MyArray((4 + i) * i + j) = i + 1
    Next
Next
Debug.Print Join(MyArray, ",")
End Sub
```

The above code will give you the output as your example.

Comment: This isn't very flexible. OP already knows how to initialize arrays in a loop but was wondering if there was a way of avoiding such explicit loops.

Comment: @JohnColeman: Just because "this isn't very flexible" according to your definition it doesn't mean deserved to be downvoted. Let alone the OP decides it

Comment: The lack of flexibility is rather extreme (hence the downvote). It isn't easily generalizable to something as simple as `Array(4,4,7,7,7,7)` still less e.g. `Array("A","A","A","B","B")`. It hard-wires in the fact that the values in the sample array consist of two successive integers.